# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

Tags: c#, azure-functions, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a Azure Function app with TargetFramework: net6.0 and Version: v4

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This function references a utility project(class library with TargetFramework: netcoreapp3.1

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This utility uses FluentEmail to manage the email functionality.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentEmail.Core" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentEmail.smtp" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentEmail.Razor" Version="3.0.2" />    
</ItemGroup>
```

On running the Azure Function App I see the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

On further analysis I found that Azure Function App uses :

[image]

Internally FluentEmail(https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail) uses:

[image]

Here goes the stacktrace details :

```
at RazorLight.Compilation.RoslynCompilationService.EnsureOptions()
   at RazorLight.Compilation.RoslynCompilationService.get_ParseOptions()
   at RazorLight.Compilation.RoslynCompilationService.CreateSyntaxTree(SourceText sourceText)
   at RazorLight.Compilation.RoslynCompilationService.CreateCompilation(String compilationContent, String assemblyName)
   at RazorLight.Compilation.RoslynCompilationService.CompileAndEmit(IGeneratedRazorTemplate razorTemplate)
   at RazorLight.Compilation.RazorTemplateCompiler.CompileAndEmit(RazorLightProjectItem projectItem)
   at RazorLight.Compilation.RazorTemplateCompiler.OnCacheMissAsync(String templateKey)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at RazorLight.EngineHandler.<CompileTemplateAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
   at RazorLight.EngineHandler.<CompileRenderAsync>d__20`1.MoveNext()
   at FluentEmail.Razor.RazorRenderer.FluentEmail.Core.Interfaces.ITemplateRenderer.Parse[T](String template, T model, Boolean isHtml)
   at FluentEmail.Core.Email.UsingTemplate[T](String template, T model, Boolean isHtml)
   at Utilities.TestMail.<SendEmail>d__4`1.MoveNext() in C:\Temp\Utilities\TestMail.cs:line 133
```

Can anyone help me here by providing some guidance?

Comment: I tested using the package you mentioned(Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions (Version: 1.1.0) which is referencing to Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection with version : 5.0.0), and your problem doesn't appear, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks @Chen for your response. The problem in this case is we are using FluentEmail which refers Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 3.1.5 and hence it is creating issues here. Any better way to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

- *We have used VS 2022 and followed the same steps given by you, below are the packages downloaded from NuGet Manager.*

[image]

- *Below is the Target Framework and version*

[image]

[image]

- *Below are the dependencies used by the solution default.*

[image]

[image]

- *And we are able to Launch the function app without any errors.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tarun Krishna for your response. I don't see the images getting loaded in your response. Can you please correct them so that I can check it and try to follow the steps.

Comment: I am able to see the images can you please refresh the browser and check again

Comment: Not sure how can I share the view that I am seeing. I tried all browsers with cache removed and still not able to see the images associated with the response. It would be great if u can update your answer once again

Comment: I see in the console response error : Uncaught ReferenceError: Svg is not defined

Comment: Please try to check with your personal network in your machine or mobile

Comment: Now I can see it @Tarun Krishna. Bu in my case the Azure Function App uses Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions (Version: 1.1.0) which is referencing to Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection with version : 5.0.0. I have mentioned it in the question already (first screenshot).

Comment: Any help on this request is much appreciated